# Плагин nestedSortable и событие click

Tags: javascript, jquery, сортировка, jquery-ui

Нашел замечательный плагин nestedSortable для jquery. Использую так:

```
<div class="list">
 <div>Item 1</div>
 <div>Item 2</div>
</div>
```

Код для jquery

```
$("div.list").nestedSortable({listType:"div"});
$("div.list div").click(function(){alert("click");});
```

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при перетаскивании элементов не срабатывало событие click?

Comment: Писать свой личный плагин вам нужно, с таким наворотом, и то мне кажется, что подобное работать не будет, хотя нужно пробовать

Comment: Ну а все таки есть мысли?